# When we install torch, what differences between different versions？

Tags: torch

When we install torch on the GPU,
fisrt to get GPU cuda version, such as  CUDA Version: 11.7  .
and there are two possible installation methods

1. select the version add cuda version，torch 2.0.0+cuxxxx, **more suitable for GPU**

```bash
pip install torch==2.0.0+cu117 torchvision==0.15.1+cu117 torchaudio==2.0.1 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117
```

2.just install，**What version is installed by default in this way? Is it more suitable for GPU or CPU?**

```bash
pip install torch
```

can someone give me some help?thanks